# Why does moving postgres database to another server change database size?

Tags: linux, postgresql

I'm moving a postgres database to another server. I use the following commands to do the dumping and loading.

```
pg_dump database_name_name > backup.sql // Dump

psql db_name < backup.sql // Load
```

I find that when I do the move the new database is 28MiB in size whereas the old database was 36MiB in size. Why is this, should I be worried that the move isn't complete?

Comment: Blocksize on the drive is different between the machines? Drives are encrypted differently, or one is and one isn't encrypted? File systems are different type between the machines? There could be quite a few things that make them different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is to be expected that the restored database is smaller than the original.

A live database always has a certain amount of bloat (empty space) that is caused by updates and deletes. That space will be reused and is no problem normally.

The restored database is densely packed and doesn't have that bloat.

However, a bloat of more than 25% is rather on the high side.
You can use [pgstattuple](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgstattuple.html) to determine if any of your tables have an undue amount of bloat.

High bloat an be caused by mass deletes or a high change rate with which autovacuum cannot keep up.
Such tables can be reorganized with `VACUUM (VERBOSE)`, and if the cause is a high change rate, you should tune autovacuum to be more aggressive on these tables.